# Laravel 7 query relationships tables

Tags: sql, laravel

I need a bit of help with getting data from tables that are in relationship.

I have 2 tables: *cards* and *statuses*:

[image]

I have following data in *cards* table:

```
id_card | card_type
--------|----------
123     | tag
281     | card
455     | card
721     | tag
```

In *statuses* table I have:

```
id_status | id_card | status_date | status_type | status_company | status_user
----------|---------|-------------|-------------|----------------|------------
1         | 123     | 2018-12-04  | available   |                |
2         | 281     | 2018-12-04  | available   |                |
3         | 455     | 2018-12-04  | available   |                |
4         | 721     | 2019-03-26  | available   |                |
5         | 281     | 2020-01-25  | issued      | Company A      | User One
6         | 123     | 2020-01-10  | issued      | Company B      | User Two
7         | 281     | 2020-01-25  | available   |                |
8         | 123     | 2020-02-02  | lost        |                |
9         | 455     | 2020-02-14  | issued      | Company C      | Third User
```

For table *cards* I have following in *Card* model:

```
public function Status() {
   return $this->hasMany('App\Status', 'id_card', 'id_card')
   ->orderBy('status_date', 'desc');
}
```

And for *statuses* table I have in *Status* model:

```
public function Card() {
   return $this->hasOne('App\Card', 'id_card', 'id_card')
}
```

Now, how should I write a query, that would return me list of cards together with values from statuses table, but only with latest status for each card, like this:

```
id_card | card_type | status_type | status_date | status_company | status_user
--------|-----------|-------------|-------------|----------------|------------
123     | tag       | lost        | 2020-02-02  |                |
281     | card      | available   | 2020-01-25  |                |
455     | card      | issued      | 2020-02-14  | Company C      | Third User
721     | tag       | available   | 2019-03-26  |
```

And is there a way, to also filter such a query i.e. to get only available cards:

```
id_card | card_type | status_type | status_date | status_company | status_user
--------|-----------|-------------|-------------|----------------|------------
281     | card      | available   | 2020-01-25  |                |
721     | tag       | available   | 2019-03-26  |                |
```

Thank you very much in advance :)

Comment: just out of curiosity, why are you changing the ID field of the tables? laravel works very well if you just leave the naming conventions how it likes it. for instance, you wouldn't have to manually define the foreign key relation in your models if you didn't change it in the table

Comment: also, why do you need more than one status per card? why don't you just update the status each time a new action happens? If the status is "lost", then i know it was "issued". Unless you're trying to keep some sort of log, do you have to have it set up this way? Updating the single status would make things much easier.

Comment: I need more statuses per card because I want to be able to see what was happening with each card in the past.

Comment: Nobody in answers mentioned relation is actually wrong. In `Status` model `public function card() {}` should have `$this->belongsTo(Card::class);` instead hasOne.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly since you have a hasMany relationship, the naming should be plural.

```
public function Statuses() {
```

Defining an [Accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) can help you on your status problem. In your Card.php model define it.

```
public function getStatusAttribute()
{
    return $this->statuses->first();
}
```

Using the appends property on your Card.php model, to tell which properties should be serialized.

```
protected $appends = ['status'];
```

This will result in your model looking like so, when it is transformed to JSON.

```
{
    "card_type": "tag",
    "status": {
        "id_card": 1,
        "status_date": "2020-02-02",
        "status_company": "Company C",
        "status_user": "Third User"
    }
}
```

If you are using it, in a Blade or PHP -context you can access like so.

```
$card->status; //your first status
```

For your query needs a simply `where()` clause combined with joining the table. For performance it would be smart to eager load statuses as you will access the first status, `with()` can be used for this.

```
Card::leftJoin('statuses', 'cards.id_card', 'statuses.id_card')
    ->where('statuses.status_type', 'available')
    ->select('cards.*')
    ->with('statuses')
    ->get();
```

Your naming of the columns is inconsistent with the `Laravel` naming convention and your data structure seems a little bit off, but this solves your problem, i would consider to rethink it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, with the help of your Accessor suggestion I can now get & search data in tables.

Just another question if possible. Is there a chance to query tables by card id or by card status or by both at the same time?

#stayhealthy

Comment: Just do ->where('statuses.status_type', 'available')->orWhere('yourothercolumn', $yourSearch);

Answer (score 3):

Laravel is a framework that works better for you if you follow some conventions. The database models standards in Laravel in your case for `Card` and `Status` would be:

[image]

Then, you could simply have:
**Status.php**

```
use App\Card;

class Status extends Model
{
  public function card()
  {
     return $this->hasOne(Card::class);
  }
}
```

**Card.php**

```
use App\Status;

class Card extends Model
{
  public function statuses()
  {
     return $this->hasMany(Status::class);
  }
}
```

Finally, you could do:

```
$cards = App\Card::with(['statuses' => function($q){
   $q->latest()->take(1);
}])->get();
```

Laravel will give out of the box a collection of Cards, with the last status attached.

To filter results based in related `Status` you could do:

```
$filter = 'available';
$cards = App\Card::with(['statuses' => function($q) use($filter) {
       $q->where('status_type', $filter)->latest()->take(1);
    }])->get();
```

Hope this helps to guide you in the right direction!

Answer (score 3):

For getting all the cards having status_type 'available'

```
Card::join('statuses', 'cards.id_card', '=', 'statuses.id_card')
->where('statuses.status_type', 'available')
->select('cards.id_card', 'cards.card_type', 'statuses.status_type', 'statuses.status_date', 'statuses.status_company', 'statuses.status_user')
->get();
```

For getting latest status you can follow these steps,

- Add following method in *Card* model

> ```
> public function latestStatus()
> {
>     return $this->hasOne('\App\Status')->latest();
> }
> ```

Method latest() orders all rows by `created_at` desc, and takes the first one. If you don't have `created_at` column you can add it in `statuses` table.

```
$cards = Card::with('latestStatus')->get();
foreach ($cards as $card) {
    echo $card->type . ' has latest status of ' . $card->latestStatus->status_type;
}
```

last but not the least, I think if you follow laravel conventions then you'll already have half of your problem solved.